# check box validation is not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

i have written code like this to validate checkbox, and it should not submit unless it is checked but it is not working

```
if(IsValid.push($("#terms").is(":checked")))
return false;
```

Comment: you can check if checkbox is checked or not using `if($("#terms").is(":checked"))`

Comment: why are you pushing in if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what "IsValid" is but you probably want something like this:

```
var checked = $("#terms").is(":checked");
IsValid.push( checked );
event.preventDefault();
```

This assumes that the code is called in a event handler.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.push` returns the new length of Array, after a successful push.

you are essentially testing if the length of the IsValid array is true, which it probably is.

you should test the condition itself:

```
if($("#terms").is(":checked"))
     return false;
```